# Model fitting for concave curve: test if asymptote or convergence exist

Tags: plotting, calculus-and-analysis, fitting, distributions, modeling

I am asking a double check if conceptually I set up proper model and proceeding in good direction to drive conclusions.

I have a distribution that looks like this:

[image]

I want to test if for increasing x values, the slope of the curve flattens.

I want to test if, for x -> Infinity, either exists an asymptote, or test if the curve could be described or approximated by a linear function, and find the slope of the linear function (see the part of the curve after first 4000, 6000 points).

I would like a double check on what I am doing:

I thought to fit the distribution like this - is it correct?

```
fModel = Fit[%, {1, x, Exp[x]}, x]
```

For 10000 points:

```
7.89305 + 0.000332542 x // for 10000 points, slope is ~ 1/3007
```

The model fits as a linear function but I puzzled because Exp[x] seems to be completely ignored, despite the initial slope of the curve. How does it actually work this fitting?

When I test the same model with other samplings, 100, 1000 points, it seems to produce results with "similar" fitting, where slope seems to goes proportionally to the number of points :

```
7.89305 + 0.000332542 x // for 10000 points, slope is ~ 1/3007

5.34334 + 0.00331581 x // for 1000 points , slope is ~ 1/301

2.90882 - 7.12146*10^-44 E^x + 0.0317902 x // for 100 points, E^x is negligible, slope ~ 1/30
```

Is it sufficient to argue that slope of the curve progressively flattens as number of data tends to infinity?

Is it accurate to say that slope "converges" to a constant value "at a rate of `1/(3 * N)` " ?

Answer (score 1):

You ask:

```
Is it sufficient to argue that the slope of the curve progressively flattens as number of data tends to infinity?
```

If you set a threshold value `epsilon` for convergence, usually in `Mathematical Analysis` books, `epsilon` is set to a very tiny number and if `epsilon>estimated value` then you can say that it converges given this specific `epsilon`. Setting the level of `epsilon` is entirely up to you.

Answer to your second question:

For the rate, given an `epsilon` value, you should conduct a regression analysis. Given `f(x)`

```
f(x) = C Exp[b x]
```

take natural `Log`:

```
Log[f(x)] = Log[C] + b x + e
```

where `e` is residual with `E[e]=0` assumed, where E is Expected Value operator. Taking derivative of the `Log` model with respect to `x` yields:

```
b=dLog[f(x)]/dx
```

which is the rate of change. This implies that Estimated(b) is the answer to your second question.

Comment: thank you but I did not understand what is your suggestion. My first question is if my model is correct given that plot, and then if analysis is correct to drive correct conclusions.

Comment: @user305883: The answer to the first question is `Yes` it is sufficient. My suggestion is `choose a small tolerance level, called `epsilon`, and if your target variable is less than `epsilon`, then conduct the rest of the analysis.

Comment: @user305883: Please note that your questions are not related to the use of `Mathematica`, and they relate to mathematical knowledge. Therefore, your question may not get sufficient attention at this forum.

Comment: I agree not strictly related to Mathematica, yet I posted it here because I am using Mathematica as tool for statistical analysis (or prototyping).